# Solr Arabic Search

Tags: solr, arabic

I want to implement Arabic Search in my solr, I am able to index the document but not able to search them.  When i refer to the documents by ID I get the document, but not when I do a search by arabic words,

**Search URL**

```
http://122.166.9.144:8080/solr/tw/select/?q=تأجير الاهلي
```

**Search Response**

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
   <int name="status">0</int>
   <int name="QTime">18</int>
     <lst name="params">
       <str name="q">ØªØ£Ø¬ÙØ± Ø§ÙØ§ÙÙÙ</str>
     </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks,

Rohit

**Edit Request/Response Header**

```
Response Headers view source
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Mon, 15 Aug 2011 15:37:25 GMT

Request Headers view source
Host    122.166.9.144:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the server fails to decode the Arabic text in the URL using the right charset. It looks vaguely like it got UTF-8 but thought it was Latin-1. Have you tried wiresharking the conversation to see exactly which URL bytes get sent to the server?

Comment: I have update the request/response header.. the q seems to be going fine.

Comment: What you're showing is not network syntax, and does not include the (hopefully percent-encoded) request URL, _as transmitted on the network_.

Comment: Thanks Henning for the suggestions.. actually the encoding was not set right on the server level (tomcat) in my case.